# Link Errors w/ SFML 2.4 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, sfml, build-error

For a while now, I have been trying to use the SFML library for C++.
However, whenever I try to run my program, I get a slew of build errors revolving around undefined symbols.  I am building from Visual Studio and I have added the include directory, the additional libraries, and the all the DLLs in bin into BOTH the source directory and the build directory.  Still, I cannot get the program to build.

My Code:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 380), "Test Window");

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // events

        window.clear();

        // drawing
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Errors:
[image]
Include Directories: SFML-2.4.2/include

Lib Directories: SFML-2.4.2/lib

Linker Input:

```
sfml-main-d.lib
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-audio-d.lib
sfml-network-d.lib
```

Comment: Are you using the SFML SDK that matches your VS version?

Comment: I am using the SFML Visual C++ 14 with Visual Studio 2017.  I got the perceived latest version I could for SFML.  Both are for Windows. (I used x86 SFML even through I have an x64 machine for compatibility)

Comment: x86 SFML on 64 system is no problem, but the SFML version needs to match your compiler so the SFML for VS 14 will **not** work. You will have to [build SFML yourself](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/compile-with-cmake.php).

Comment: Try ordering the libs correctly e.g. network at the top, then audio-graphics-window-system

Answer (score 0):

I know this is like one and a half year old but I had the same errors and I have resolved them.
The following Pastebin files are my config and task files which(in my case work fine with Visual Studio Code Version 1.32.3 read the bottom for what you will have to change) 
Date:2019-03-14
Electron:3.1.6
Chrome:66.0.3359.181
Node.js:10.2.0
V8:6.6.345.32
Os: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134

```
c_cpp_properties.json: https://pastebin.com/3gw8J4d2``
task.json: https://pastebin.com/s1rjswWG``
```

**IMPORTANT:**
change the following:
(If you have MinGW installed on the standard path)

- c_cpp_properties.json:  K:/libs/SFML-2.5.1/include has to be changed
  to your installation path of SFML be sure to change it in the browse path too!!!
- tasks.json:
- "-IK:/libs/SFML-2.5.1/", change    K:/libs/SFML-2.5.1/include to your
  installation path of SFML
- "-LK:/libs/SFML-2.5.1/lib", change K:/libs/SFML-2.5.1/lib again to
  your installation path of SFML

a few mistakes I made:

- I didn't delete the K: in "-L**K:**/libs/SFML-2.5.1/lib"
- I didn't have g++ in command at the top of tasks.json
- I didn't use the right compiling/link paths (search for all paths you
  use in your browser before giving up)

A few helpful Links:

- https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/ (for MinGW be sure to
  select GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (DW2) - 32-bit)
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp (Documentation on
  how to compile in Vs with c++)
- https://discordapp.com/invite/nr4X7Fh (Discord Server of SFML where
  are a lot of helpful people for the library)

I hope I helped 
If you have any question you can message me on Reddit u/Spagetti_Lord (most active)